# Unable to start debugging. Not implemented. Error on VS code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Hi i recently started using VS code for my C++ course. I am trying to get the debugger to work but even with hours of trying to figure out what's wrong i still get the following error "Unable to start debugging. Not implemented." I am a bit unsure on what that means let alone how to solve it. My launch.json file looks like this. Thank you in advance for the help.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(Windows) Launch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "Assigment_1.C++",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use Visual Studio Code text editor instead of real Visual Studio.

Comment: Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are completely different products.

Comment: `"Assigment_1.C++"` are you sure that's the exact path and filename of your executable from compilation?

Comment: Do you have any compiler/debugger for C++ installed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough Karma to post in the comment thread but I wanted to say that I don't think it matters that you're using vs code instead of visual studio. It says in the debug console that the C/C++ extionsion is compatible with both, and this is the .json that is automatically generated by vs code. I'm having the same issue trying to run C. I've reached out to microsoft support. Let me know if you've figured it out, thanks.

Alternatively, it seems to work if you just download the code runner extension and then right click and choose run code instead. At least it did for me using C. Still trying to figure out how to use it with the debugger however.

Answer (score 0):

First, create your C++ folder (mine is cpp test), and create the main.cpp file.

Then, after making the main method just click <kbd>F5</kbd>, and VS Code will pop up a box asking whether C++ (GDB) or C++ (Windows):

[image: refer the photo]

Now, click on C++(GDB/LLDB), then on g++.exe (Build and Debug active file), and VS Code will generate the lanch.json file.

Then go to the main.cpp file, Just click <kbd>F5</kbd>, and it will run without any problem.

**Note:** make sure that you have installed Cygwin64 on your computer; MinGW is also possible.

Answer (score -1):

The json file below worked for me

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "D:/mingw/bin/gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).